# Can't import fl.controls in Flash IDE

Tags: flash, import, ide, controls

I'm coding in the Adobe Flash CS5 IDE. I swear fl.controls used to be importable, but now it's just not there. I *may* have removed the package from wherever it was when trying to use it in Flash Builder. Anyone know how I can get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a control for Flash linkage.

[image: flash-components]

`fl.controls` package will then be available.

[image: flash-controls]

Flash controls package is part of Flash Pro and can be added by SWC or via code:

**Adding by SWC:**

*Windows:*
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs\flash.swc

*Mac OS X:*
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc

**Adding by source folder:**

*Windows:*
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface

*Mac OS X:*
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Component Source/ActionScript 3.0/User Interface